# How to get length Image column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, file

How to get length Image column in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Ill try with

```
SELECT len(File) FROM dbo.tblFiles
```

Comment: len function works for getting image field length, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(File) FROM  dbo.tblFiles
```